# I have Problems when uploaded the image on my product in backend magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, cookie, form-key, magento2.3.2

today when try to upload the image on my product, magento show me this error
[image]

firts time magento show me this error becauses, before i edited all my products, and now magento show me this.

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

- `sudo rm -rf var/session/` *in project root*
- `sudo rm -rf var/cache/` *in project root*
- `php bin/magento cache:flush`
- Clear browser cache and cookies for domain
- `DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path='web/cookie/cookie_domain';` *in database*
- `DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path='web/cookie/cookie_path';` *in database*